# How to speed up a loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to speed up this short piece of code

```
      max_x=array([max(x[(id==dummy)]) for dummy in ids])
```

`x` and `id` are numpy arrays of the same dimensions and `ids` is an array of smaller dimension.
What is the fast way to do it using vectorial operation?

Comment: you're right, thanks for the comments. maybe I should rephrase my question because what I'm most interested in is to speed up my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easy to do vectorize further (as far as I see), unless id has some structure. Otherwise a bottleneck might be doing `id==dummy` often, but the only solution I can think of would be the use of sorting, and due to the lack of a reduce functionality for np.max() still requires quite a bit of python code (Edit: There actually is a reduce function through np.fmax available). This is about 3x faster for a x being 1000x1000 and id/ids being in 0..100, but as its rather complex, its only worth it for larger problems with many ids:

```
def max_at_ids(x, id, ids):
    # create a 1D view of x and id:
    r_x = x.ravel()
    r_id = id.ravel()
    sorter = np.argsort(r_id)

    # create new sorted arrays:
    r_id = r_id[sorter]; r_x = r_x[sorter]

    # unfortunatly there is no reduce functionality for np.max...

    ids = np.unique(ids) # create a sorted, unique copy, just in case

    # w gives the places where the sorted arrays id changes:
    w = np.where(r_id[:-1] != r_id[1:])[0] + 1
```

I originally offered this solution which does a pure python loop over the slices, but below is a shorter (and faster) version:

```
    # The result array:
    max_x = np.empty(len(ids), dtype=r_x.dtype)
    start_idx = 0; end_idx = w[0]
    i_ids = 0
    i_w = 0

    while i_ids < len(ids) and i_w < len(w) + 1:
        if ids[i_ids] == r_id[start_idx]:
            max_x[i_ids] = r_x[start_idx:end_idx].max()
            i_ids += 1
            i_w += 1
        elif ids[i_ids] > r_id[start_idx]:
            i_w += 1
        else:
            i_ids += 1
            continue # skip updating start_idx/end_idx

        start_idx = end_idx
        # Set it to None for the last slice (might be faster to do differently)
        end_idx = w[i_w] if i_w < len(w) else None

    return ids, max_x
```

EDIT: improved version for calculation of the maxium for each slice:

There is a way to remove the python loop by the use of `np.fmax.reduceat`, which might outperform the previous one a lot if the slices are small (and is actually quite elgant):

```
# just to 0 at the start of w
# (or calculate first slice by hand and use out=... keyword argument to avoid even
# this copy.
w = np.concatenate(([0], w))
max_x = np.fmin.reduceat(r_x, w)
return ids, max_x
```

Now there are probably some small things where it is possible to make this a little faster.
If id/ids has some structure it should be possible to simplify the code, and maybe use a different approach to achieve a much larger speedup. Otherwise the speedup of this code should be large, as long as there are many (unique) ids (and x/id arrays are not very small).
Note that the code enforces np.unique(ids), which is probably a good assumption though.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It's been extremely useful. It speeds up the calculation by roughly 98%.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a shorter/faster version by using `np.fmax.reduceat` to avoid the python loop over all slices.

Answer (score 1):

Using `x[(id==dummy)].max()` instead of the built-in `max` should give some speed-up.

Comment: Great suggestion, but that speed up my calculation of only 2%. It is really the only possible way?

Comment: Probably not, let's hope someone else chimes in.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.ndimage.maximum`does exactly that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as nd

N = 100  # number of values
K = 10   # number of class

# generate random data
x   = np.random.rand(N)
ID  = np.random.randint(0,K,N)  # random id class for each xi's
ids = np.random.randint(0,K,5)  # select 5 random class

# do what you ask
max_per_id = nd.maximum(x,labels=ID,index=ids)

print dict(zip(ids,max_per_id))
```

If you want to compute the max for all ids, do `ids = ID`

Note that if a particular class in `ids` is not found in `ID`(i.e. no x is labeled by that class) then the maximum return for that class is `0`.